# RoR add where to do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am listing the contents of a table called books.
To show all the records, I use:
      <% @books.each do |books| %>

Can I add a where clause so that only matching books are listed?
    <% Books.where(:type_id => '1') do |books| %>

Thanks

Comment: yes you can: `Books.where(:type_id => 1) # => Array of Books` and then use `<% Books.where(:type_id => 1).each do |book| %>`

Comment: You can but also consider using instance variable from the controller side. `@books = Books.where(:type_id => 1)`

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you get an error? You already have the answer from nice people here, but it seems you could have tried it in a few seconds and gotten an answer, or at least posted what errors you were running in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need .each to iterate, and the Model name is usually singular

```
<% Book.where(:type_id => 1, :author_id => 2).each do |book| %>
  <%= book.title %>
<% end %>
```

Edit: added second condition to query since it was asked in comment.

Comment: That works - thanks!  How would I add a second AND test like :author_id = '2'?

Comment: Thanks!  One more question - how would I change the :author_id to be not equal to 2.  I tried !=

Comment: @DaveBurton You'll need to use parameter binding and drop down to some SQL for that: where('author_id != ?', 2). Alternately, you can use https://github.com/ernie/squeel to make what you described work, but it's not like that out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can do this as 'Book' (I believe it should be Book not Books when we are getting the model) is the Activerecord model you are referring, But as a practise you shouldn't do this because, here you are getting the business login to your view.

Usually business logic should reside in your model layer.